Classifying Geodesics in Sub-Riemannian Geometry
If $(M,D,g)$ is a sub-Riemannian manifold, $D$ is bracket generating, and $q\in M$, then the Rashevskii-Chow theorem (along with a few other lemmas) implies that there is a geodesic neighborhood about $q$ in $M$ that is totally covered by extremal geodesics which remain tangent to $D$. In regular Riemannian geometry, geodesics come from a second order diff eq, so they are parametrized by the initial point $q$ and initial tangent vector $\gamma ‘ (0)$. The text I’m reading motivates the proper way to classify sub-Riemannian geodesics by claiming that sub-Riemannian geodesics cannot be parametrized by initial tangent vectors because $D$ is lower dimension than $M$ and, therefore, there aren’t enough admissible velocities to account for the entire geodesic ball about $q$. This is fine, it’s clear that this is the case. My confusion arises from the existence of this geodesic ball and the fact that the set of initial tangent vectors is a proper subspace of $T_q M$. How can you have a geodesic neighborhood of $q$ in which all of the geodesics remain (at least locally) tangent to $D$? Wouldn’t some of those geodesics have to have initial velocities which aren’t in $D_q$ and, therefore, not be admissible? It seems like a contradiction to me and I’m obviously misunderstanding something.
